# Mudar o response de array para objeto

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

estou fazendo um get e o response está vindo assim:

```
[
 {"cep":"01050-070",
  "rua":"Rua Álvaro de Carvalho",
  "bairro":"Centro",
  "cidade":"São Paulo",
  "estado":"SP"}
]
```

Eu gostaria que o response viesse assim:

```
{
  "cep": "01050-070",
  "rua":"Rua Álvaro de Carvalho",
  "bairro":"Centro",
  "cidade":"São Paulo",
  "estado":"SP"
}
```

O meu método está assim:

```
searchCep () {
  this.$validator
    .validateAll()
    .then(success => {
      if (success) {
        const url = `http://localhost:4001/${this.cep}`
        axios.get(url)
          .then(response => this.data = response.data)
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
      }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quem gera a resposta é o servidor, se você não tem como alterar lá só te resta lidar com o que recebe:

```
if (response.data.length > 0) this.data = response.data[0];
```

PS: Você sabe que essa URL `http://localhost:4001...` só vai funcionar na sua máquina né?

Comment: Sei sim, to só estudando. Como ficaria o método completo com essa sua alteração?